# How to sort 3D array in first dimension based on another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I'm currently converting some code from Matlab to Python.

I have a 3D array with dimensions based on longitude x latitude x time. The longitude is currently [-180 180] and I'd like to convert it to [0 360] in order to interpolate it to the same grid as a different variable. Once I convert it, I need to sort the values in the 3D array to match the sorted [0  360 values].

My code in Matlab:

```
SSS_ships=flip(SSS_ships,2);
SSS_ship.lon2=wrapTo360(SSS_interp.lon);
[SSS_ship.lon2,ix]=sort(SSS_ship.lon2);
SSS_ship.sss=SSS_ships(ix,:,:);
```

My code so far in Python:

```
 idx=np.where(SSS_lon < 0)
 SSS_lon[idx]=SSS_lon[idx]+360
```

I'm stuck on finding a function that will allow me to sort the data like in Matlab. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the difference is that in Matlab, you seem to have an array of records or something of that sort (with a field `lon2`), while here, you have separate arrays (at least, the only one you've shown is `SSS_lon`, with no mention whatsoever of other arrays containing other informations, such as latitude and time.

Assuming that what you have are 3 different arrays

```py
import numpy as np
SSS_lon=np.random.rand(10)*360-180
SSS_lat=np.random.rand(10)*180-90
SSS_tim=np.random.rand(10)
```

Then, you can sort by extracting the sorting index with `argsort` and then applying them to all 3 arrays

```
ix=SSS_lon.argsort()
SSS_lon2=SSS_lon[ix]
SSS_lat2=SSS_lat[ix]
SSS_tim2=SSS_tim[ix]
```